# seeking debugging help, Why is this tokenizer not copying the array properly?

Tags: c, tokenize

in this assignment I have to create a tokeniser function in c that copies the contents of a string into another while removing spaces. It returns the position at which the next token should be looked for.

A token is a string of chars or a single operator char.

In my attempt, the counter that detects and bypasses the spaces somehow stops the contents being copied into the result string, after the first token. Here is my code:

```
int checkOperators(char str[], char operators[], int i){
    int counter = 0;
    while(operators[counter]!='\0')
    {
        if(str[i]==operators[counter]) return 1;
        counter++;
    }
  return 0;
}

int tokenise_ops(char str[], int start, char result[], char operators[]){

    int i = start;
    int j = start;

    while(str[i]==' ' && str[i]!='\0'){
        i++;
    }

    if(checkOperators(str,operators,i)==1)
    {
        result[j]= str[i];
        i++;
        return i;
    }

    while(str[i]!='\0')
    {
        result[j]= str[i];
        i++;
        j++;
        if(str[i]==' ' || checkOperators(str,operators,i)==1) return i;
    }

    return -1;
}

int main()
{
    char str[]="26.6 * 7.9 + 3";
    char result[256];
    char operators[]={'+','-','*','/','^','\0'};

    int start=0;

    start = tokenise_ops(str,start,result,operators);
    while ( start != -1 )
    {
        printf("%s\n", result);
        start = tokenise_ops(str, start, result,operators);
    }
    printf("%s\n", result);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `int j = start;` --> `int j = 0;` Post the `checkOperators` function.

Comment: The result string is not null-terminated.

Comment: `while(str[i]==' ')` does not take care of str len (null-terminator)

Comment: Sorry, I had the null-terminator accounted for in another version. If the while counter is not present it will print copies of the array as it tokenizes it, but when it is it will print '26.6' per token.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your tokenize function can be:

```
int tokenise_ops(char str[], int start, char result[], char operators[])
{
    int i = start;
    int j = 0;

    while ((str[i]==' ') && (str[i]!='\0'))
    {
        i++;
    }


    while(str[i]!='\0')
    {
        if(str[i]==' ' || checkOperators(str,operators,i)==1)
        {
            printf("Test2: %c\n", str[i]);
            result[j] = '\0';

            return i;
        }
        else
        {
            printf("Test: %c\n", str[i]);
            result[j] = str[i];
            i++;
            j++;
        }
    }

    result[j] = '\0';

    return -1;
}
```

1. `j` is  the `result` index, so it must start from `0` each call
2. while loop should store chars if they don't match the tokens, and null terminate result when the token is found.
3. `result` must be null-terminated when the whole `str` is parsed.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I've only started c last september. The null terminate the result solved my worries. I know is ugly and not efficient but is mine and now works.

Comment: Ok, I deleted my answer, I need to learn stackflow protocols. I did upvote your solution, but I don't have enough reputation to have it displayed. Thanks again.

Comment: @Bitan78 Set the answer as correct. Is the check down the votes. You're welcome.